# selected drop down values will never display with other drop down

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have three drop down box with same option. now, if I select one drop down option then other two drop down will never contain this option. and select drop down value will show as select.

after that select other drop down then this selected option will show as select but other two drop down will never contain option.

this is my code here, i want to implement.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <%= f.label :area_1, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label mt10' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <%= f.select :area_1, options_for_select(industries), {:prompt => "Please select industry"}, {:class => "form-control", :id => "area_1"} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.label :area_2, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label mt20' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10 mt10" id="area_2_select">
    <%= f.select :area_2, options_for_select(industries), {:prompt => "Please select industry"}, {:class => "form-control", :id => "area_2"} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.label :area_3, class: 'col-lg-2 control-label mt20' %>
  <div class="col-lg-10 mt10">
    <%= f.select :area_3, options_for_select(industries), {:prompt => "Please select industry"}, {:class => "form-control", :id => "area_3"} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

in above code i have added three select box and this box value coming from industries method that is define in helper like this

```
def industries
[
  ['Agriculture & Mining', 'Ag', 1],
  ['Business Services', 'Bs', 2],
  ['Computers & Electronics', 'Ce', 3],
  ['Consumer Services', 'Cs', 4],
  ['Education', 'Ed', 5],
]
end
```

then i have tried to make function with on change event like

```
$( document ).on('change', '#area_1', function(){
  values = $('#area_1').val();

})
```

please let me know how can solve this thing.

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add code which you have written so far on it

Comment: yes sure ... give me 10 more minutes please.